# Where can you get list of all Basecamps that user has access to?

Tags: api, basecamp

[Basecamp API](http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/index.shtml) allows a lot of things but it's all based on one URL:

```
http://your_basecamp.basecamphq.com
```

Thing is, you can use one 37 Signals account with multiple basecamps. So, where can I find a list off all basecamps that user can see? Similar to [Launchpad](https://launchpad.37signals.com/), but in XML/JSON?
There has to be a way, for example [BaseApp](http://getbaseapp.com/) lists all your basecamp URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's no such API for that and the only way is to parse Launchpad page and fake logging in...

Problem is, that simple change in their HTML would break this functionality, so I decided to have this part on my server, so I can fix it without waiting for Apple to approve my app to MAS. If someone is interested, you can get this Django view here: https://gist.github.com/1423289